# Javascript in IE vs Firefox

Tags: javascript, dom

The following script works fine in IE7 but fails to execute in Firefox 3. The div tag which was display: none; shows in IE but never in FF. I am not a client / javascript guy... thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.getElementById("Fred1_Panel").style.setAttribute("display","inline");//]]>

</script>
```

Comment: Do you have the HTML code this modifying as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("Fred1_Panel").style.display = '';
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("Fred1_Panel").style.display = 'inline';
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work in both browsers:

```
document.getElementById("Fred1_Panel").style.display = 'inline';
```

Comment: thanks. both fix my issue. gave the answer to the guy with the fewer points. sure wish I could assign "2" correct answers.

Comment: @Andrew. Just FYI, typically you would accept the first answer if two are the same.  Glad to help out.

Answer (score 2):

In FF, starting with either Tools | Error Console, or FireBug's console is a good way to see what errors are occurring.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
document.getElementById("Fred1_Panel").style.display = "inline";
```

In general if you encounter problems in Firefox you can easily discover the exact problem (and maybe find out the solution) using Firebug plugin or simply seeing at the Error console.